# What does fscanf() put into char pointers?

Tags: c, string, scanf

If I have the file

f1.txt that only contains the following

```
stringhere
```

and the code (imagine `fp` is a `FILE` pointer to `f1.txt`, opened in `r` mode)

```
char *data = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
fscanf(fp, "%s", data);
```

What is stored into `data` from `fscanf()`? Does it assign a string literal in read only memory to `data`?

Comment: It copies the string into `data`, assuming `data` is big enough to hold it. Which means you should specify a maximum length for the string to read, or `data` may overflow.

Comment: Can you tell me if it does or doesn't make `data` point to a string literal in read only memory?

Comment: it doesn't. C requires programmers to manage memory on their own.

Comment: Yes. How would you expect it to do so, as you're not passing a pointer to a string (i.e., `char **`), but a string (`char *`)? It can't modify the address of the pointer you pass to it.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Right I see. Am I right in thinking that only `char *`'s that are initialised by a double quoted string are pointing into read only memory?

Comment: @doukremt But it could store the string from the file into read only memory and then make `data` point to it

Comment: @CSStudent in your case, the string is modifiable. but if you goes `char *str = "stringhere!";` it's not.

Comment: @CSStudent No it can't. First, data can not be written into read-only memory (by definition). Second, it only receives a copy of the pointer you pass to it, so reassigning it to something else would only be local the function scope.

Comment: Note that according to Murphy's Law, it is inevitable that f1.txt will eventually be altered to contain a string longer than `MAX_STR_LEN-1` bytes, thereby creating bad behavior in the `fscanf()`. Discovering other reasons to avoid the `scanf()` family of functions is left as an exercise.

Comment: @doukremt Ah ofcourse, pass by value. Thanks

Comment: @RussellBorogove What would you suggest in using for reading strings from files then? In my actual code I have given a length specifier for the format specifier.

Comment: That's better; you may get truncated data but at least you won't get your heap smashed. Ideally you'd read a moderately-sized chunk at a time, enlarging the buffer with `realloc()` or its moral equivalent as needed, until you reached EOF or decided to error out -- or find a library that does this kind of thing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string read from the file is copied into the dynamic memory allocated by the `malloc` call and pointed to by `data`.

You'll basically have something that looks like this (addresses are pulled out of thin air and not meant to represent any real platform):

```
Item          Address               0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03
----          -------               ---- ---- ---- ----
data          0x7ff84000            0x7f 0xff 0xf0 0x00
...
"stringhere"  0x7ffff000             's'  't'  'r'  'i'
              0x7ffff004             'n'  'g'  'h'  'e'
              0x7ffff008             'r'  'e' 0x00 0x??
```

No string literals or read-only memory are involved in this particular operation.

Comment: From my comment in the question section:  Am I right in thinking that only `char *`'s that are initialised by a double quoted string are pointing into read only memory?

Comment: @CSStudent: Only if the platform puts string literals in read-only memory; not all do.